# Custom HTTP request parsing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to parse the incoming HTTP request in ASP.NET Core, with no luck. I've read about the EnableBuffering method, but I don't want to reread the incoming stream, I want to replace the internal HTTP request parsing.

I've tried the simplest code I could think of, but the Body remains empty:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Run(async context =>
{
    var total = 0;
    var bytes = new byte[1024];
    var count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    while (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            total++;
        }
        count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(total.ToString());
});
app.Run();
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Is there a body to begin with? `Body` is a Stream so you can use `Stream.CopyTo` or `CopyToAsync` right away. There are better ways though. To parse the content you need to know the encoding, which is specified in the `Content-Type` header. The doc page [Use HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/use-http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0) shows the possible ways of reading the body - through the stream itself, BodyReader to conserve memory, `ReadFormAsync` to read form fields directly etc

Comment: As the docs explain, `EnableBuffering` is used to allow other middleware and eventually endpoints to read the request. The body is sent as a stream of bytes from the client so it can only be read once. You can't ask the client to go back and resend the request. To allow endpoints to receive the body, `EnableBuffering` is needed, to buffer the entire body and pass it on

Comment: BTW there's no `WebApplication.Run(Action<HttpContext>)`. Did you mean `builder.Run(...)` perhaps?

Comment: No repro. When I make a request with a body, I get the length back, eg `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}'   http://localhost:5125` returns `35`

Comment: You're right, as I wrote below, I was expecting the headers to be there and I had not tried with a content (silly me!). The Body is REALLY the request Body, not the whole request. Thank you for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's no point in trying custom parsing without understanding how HTTP and ASP.NET Core work

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate `app.Run()`, perhaps removing the latter will fix your issue

Comment: I don't know why, the first Run doesn't block, the second one does. And the first one is indeed called. If you know why, I'm interested :)

Comment: @FrançoisLemaire the first one is the `Run(IApplicationBuilder, RequestDelegate)` extension method that adds middleware. The second is `WebApplication.Run()` that runs the application. It only compiles because `WebApplication` implements the `IApplicationBuilder` interface. You don't see such code because people add middleware in the `builder` before calling `build`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just taking the time to write your own question so that somebody else can answer it is enough to move you forward. I was expecting the headers to be part of the Body, thus I was testing my app with a simple GET request. I've tried a POST in application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and voilà, the Body contains my form (and just my form, not the headers).

Moreover, with the following code (and sending test=tralala):

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
  string s = context.Request.Form["test"];
  var total = 0;
  var bytes = new byte[1024];
  var count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  while (count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      total++;
    }
    count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  }

  await context.Response.WriteAsync(total.ToString());
});
```

s contains "tralala" and the Body si empty. Whereas with the following code:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
  var total = 0;
  var bytes = new byte[1024];
  var count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  while (count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      total++;
    }
    count = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  }
  string s = context.Request.Form["test"];
  await context.Response.WriteAsync(total.ToString());
});
```

The body contains my form and s is empty. My conclusion: the soonest you can get the HttpRequest, the headers are parsed and you are at the beginning of the payload. If you try to use any methods or properties from the HttpRequest, the Body is read whole.
I'll mark my own question as solved and I will let it here for others to see.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is highly unusual and inefficient code. You don't need all that code to read the body either. `Body` is a `Stream` so you can use a `StreamReader` to read all the text.  If you want *form* data, `Request.ReadFormAsync` will do it

Comment: It's just a test, now that I think I have understood how request.Body works, I will write a more interesting parsing code :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no repro. Posting a request with eg :

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:5125
```

Returns

```
35
```

There's no reason to specify the content type either, or sending JSON. `curl --request POST --data 'banana' http://localhost:5125` returns `6`.

The code is unusual for *several* reasons. Middleware is typically added on the *builder*, not the WebApplication instance. It works in this way because `WebApplication` implements `IApplicationBuilder`. This is meant for simple applications that don't need to customize the defaults at all, eg:

```
var app= WebApplication.Create();
app.Run(async context =>
{
    using var reader=new StreamReader(context.Request.Body,Encoding.UTF8);
    var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(text.Length.ToString());
});
app.Run();
```

or

```
var app= WebApplication.Create();
app.Run(async context =>
{
    var dto = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyDTO>();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(dto.Username);
});
app.Run();

record MyDTO(string Username, string Password);
```

There's a `ReadFormAsync` convenience method too:

```
var app= WebApplication.Create();
app.Run(async context =>
{
    var fields= await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(fields["username"]);
});
app.Run();
```

Posting this:

```
curl -X POST -F 'username=user' -F 'password=something' http://localhost:5125
```

Returns

```
user
```

The ASP.NET Core methods use System.IO.Pipeline to avoid allocations as much as possible. Instead of creating a `byte[]` buffer for every request, they use PipeReader and pooled buffers.

To get the same benefits, one can use the PipeReader instance returned by `Request.BodyReader`. Using a PipeReader is an [advanced and more complex scenario though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#pipereader).